# active vibrations_damping systems

Tags: control-engineering

I'v been preparing a seminar related to vibrations_damping systems when it come to the two topics: the active controller systems and the passive ones, could anyone please tell the simplest definitions and differences between them both, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

a passive controller system contains only passive components: springs, masses, and friction devices. it has no motors, sensors, actuators nor an external power source. an active controller system has all of these.

Comment: thank you very much for answering such naive question - as others said-, I appreciate your help ^_^ .